# How can i check every alphabet inside one string variable?

Tags: c#, string, binary

How can i check every alphabet inside one string variable?
I am trying to make a program that can translate sentences into ones and zeros.
look at the code below, that is how much i have done right now. i can read values from a text file and write out the values for only one letter. i want to know how i can write my code to be able to check every letter in a sentence.![enter image description here][1]

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();


string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Values.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    string value = lines[i].Substring(4);
    string identifier = lines[i].Substring(0, 1);
    dictionary.Add(identifier, value);
}

string sentence = Console.ReadLine();
if (sentence == "A")
{
    Console.WriteLine(dictionary[sentence]);
}
else if (sentence == "B")
{
    Console.WriteLine(dictionary[sentence]);
}


Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I got help from a friend. Thx for they help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want iterate over chars in your sentence variable you can use foreach:

```
foreach (var item in sentence)
{
    ....
}
```

In this example item is variable of char type. You can call ToString() method to convert it to string.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this as C# all you really have to do is read from the string like an array since C# allows indexing

```
String wordzyo = "ABCDEF";
char aLeter = wordzyo[0];  // read "A" into CHAR "aLeter"
```

If this is Java and not C# you would use "aLeter.charAt(0);"

Don't know why your asking this? It's been asked like a hundred times before...